# Hashtable rehash condition not evaluating Java

Tags: java

I am designing a Hashtable with linear probing collision resolution. I have designed a capacity which defines the number of buckets, and a load factor. When the number of elements in the hashtable exceeds the product of the capacity and the load factor, the array should be rehashed. For some reason, the method is not even being called in my code. Here is my main method:

```
public class MyJHUHashMap<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V> implements JHUHashMap<K, V>{

    private int cap;
    private int numElements;
    private double loadFactor;
    private Node<K,V>[] hashtable;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyJHUHashMap<Integer, Integer> m = new MyJHUHashMap<>();
        m.put(1, 1);
        m.put(2, 2);
        m.put(3, 3);
        m.put(4, 4);
        m.put(5, 5);
        m.put(6, 6);
        m.put(7, 7);
        System.out.println(m.cap);
        System.out.println(m.size());
        for(int i=0; i<m.hashtable.length; i++) {
            if(m.hashtable[i] != null)
                System.out.println(m.hashtable[i].key);
        }
    }
```

and here is my code:

```
private final class Node<K extends Comparable<? super K>, V>  {
        public K key;
        public V val;

        public Node() {
            this.key = null;
            this.val = null;
        }

        public Node(K theKey, V theValue) {
            this.key = theKey;
            this.val = theValue;
        }
    } 

    public MyJHUHashMap() {
        this.cap = 11;
        this.numElements = 0;
        this.loadFactor = 0.5;
        this.hashtable = new Node[cap];
    }

    public MyJHUHashMap(int pInitCap, double pLoadFactor) {
        if(pInitCap > 0 && pLoadFactor > 0) {
            this.cap = pInitCap;
            this.loadFactor = pLoadFactor;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        this.numElements = 0;
        this.hashtable = new Node[cap];
    }

    @Override
    public V put(K key, V value) {
        if(containsKey(key)) {
            int foundindex = find(key);
            V prevObject = this.hashtable[foundindex].val;
            //hashtable[foundindex] = new Node(key, value);
            this.hashtable[foundindex].val = value;
            return prevObject;
        }
        int index = key.hashCode() % cap;
        if(this.hashtable[index] == null) {
            this.hashtable[index] = new Node<K,V>(key, value);
            this.numElements++;
            return null;
        } 
        boolean found = false;
        //index += 1;
        while(found) {
            index += 1;
            if(hashtable[index] == null) {
                hashtable[index] = new Node<K,V>(key, value);
                this.numElements++;
                found = true;
                //return null;
            }
            //index += 1;
        }
        if(this.numElements > this.cap * this.loadFactor) {
            System.out.println("Rehashing...");
            rehashAndResize();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void rehashAndResize() {
        //Node<K,V>[] temp = new Node[this.hashtable.length*2];
        //Node<K,V>[] temp = new Node[this.hashtable.length*2];
        System.out.println("Calling rehash method");
        MyJHUHashMap<K,V> temp = new MyJHUHashMap<K, V>(this.hashtable.length * 2, this.loadFactor);
        for(int i=0; i<this.hashtable.length; i++) {
            temp.put(this.hashtable[i].key, this.hashtable[i].val);
        }

        this.hashtable = temp.hashtable;
    }
```

"Rehashing" and "Calling rehash method" are not being printed, so the method is not being called, which I can't fathom why. I input 7 elements, and the hashtable prints out 7 correctly when I ask it the number of elements, so why isn't the condition being evaluated?

EDIT: Ok, after closer inspection I found that the rehash method was never being reached because the method was returning early. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is `this.numElements > this.cap * this.loadFactor` actually *true* during the run of your program?  That'd be the only way your method gets invoked...

Comment: well I added 7 elements, it knows there are 7 elements, and 7 > 11*0.5, so it should be true

Comment: Are you **sure** about that?  Again, that expression must evaluate to `false` if you're not calling your method.

Comment: What happened was the method was returning whenever a new value had been inserted and there was no collision, so therefore the rehashing method was never reached. Thank you for your help!